# Proper input value reset

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a list of elements, populated with the value of an input and I want that input to be cleared of the value after a submit button was clicked. Submit button has to be disabled until an input has value. I'm halfway there, an error, I assume, is in the following logic:

```
// Disable submit button until input has value
$('.submit-input').prop('disabled', true);
$('.input-value').keyup(function () {
    $('.submit-input').prop('disabled', this.value == '' ? true : false);
})

// After populating a list
$('.input-value').val('');
```

I check the value of an input upon each `keyup` and after I press a submit button value is appended to the list of elements and resets via `val('')`. But after I select an input again, submit button is active even though input has no value, hitting backspace, for instance, relaunches `keyup` and submit button behaves as intended. I figure it's because `keyup` didn't fire since the last action was a click on a submit button. I'm pretty much a total noob in javascript, please put me in a right direction. Any tips on general logic are also very welcomed!
Entire code is in the following [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3shpgtt/).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button again as soon as it is clicked.

```
 $('.submit-input').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        /* Other code goes here */
});
```

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/c3shpgtt/2/